Lower leaves of lavender sapplings turning dark
I've grown these lavenders from seeds, and noticed though that some of the lower leaves on these saplings are starting to turn dark.
I'm not sure whether this is something I should be concerned about, but it seems that this is only occuring on the lower leaves.

Thanks

Which kind of soil did you use? Seedling soil do not have nutrients, and you may need to consider pH. But for now I would not worry too much (nothing really wrong)
